# Implicit sharing for custom classes in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

The implicit sharing is an interesting feature of Qt value container classes, so having custom implicitly shared classes would be a great in case of performance and memory usage, i am figuring out how to implementing it.

For a custom class containing some POD members and Qt value type members the implicit sharing would be automatically available for each member which is a Qt value types such as QString, QByteArray and ...

In this approach, the problem is the each member has its specific sharedPtr and reference count, for a big object with more than 50 implicitly shared members, it think its a loss of performance to check the reference count of each object independently  (for detaching)
From my point of view, its better to make whole object implicitly shared, which reduces the total memory consumption and operations needed for shared classes.

From COW (Copy on Write) point of view, this approach is better because the COW will be performed on smaller granularity, how ever for read only objects it doesn't worth much

**Q1:**
Can anyone explain me the drawback and advantages of implicitly sharing of custom class containing large number of members (>50)

**Q2:**
As far as i know, the implicitly shared class will benefits from SharedData Class inside Qt namespace, so is it possible to have a custom implicitly shared class at all ?! what about Qt type members inside custom class?
I don't mean move semantics of C++11 which is already known, the Qt one is more powerful

Answer (score 2):

The drawbacks and advantages of implicit sharing for classes containing a large number of members depends on the size of the said members. And they are exactly the same as for other classes like QString. You pay a constant time for the reference counting for each write operation, but you do not have to pay for the deep copy (memory allocation, member variable constructor calls, etc.), at least not immediately. Whether or not you should pay for reference counting, depend on your use case: if you make a lot of read only copy of a large data set, then implicit sharing will boost your performance, but if you make a lot of copy of small objects that will be written to, there is no point to implicit sharing.

`QSharedData` and `QSharedDataPointer` are useful tools, but you are free to use any other implementation of copy-on-write for your own classes. Even if they contain Qt classes.

Also do not compare move semantics and copy-on-write, they do different things.

Comment: Thanks, i noticed the move semantics in contrast of no deep copy in implicitly shared classes
How i can encapsulate different class members inside a raw pointer given by QSharedData  ? it isn't documented well

Comment: You have a complete example in `QSharedDataPointer` documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshareddatapointer.html#details